# How should I save my application data that is created by users in the database which consists of links and texts?

Tags: database, types

I have data something like this. Please have a look at the image to know the exact type of data I am dealing with.

[Image of what is the type of content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJzqu.png)

Can you recommend me the ways to save the element in the database? I am also thinking of the security of the site and the ease of using the data in multiple devices.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but I think you could use Markdown for the text content. That way, you just store text (including the links) to your database and have your Markdown renderer take care of formatting such as underlining links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first solution is to save all of your data in two tables,

   Article (ID (int), Content (text)).   The content is an html data like bellow:

   ```html
      Hey, I should say that <a id='{linkId}' href='{link address}'>{linkText}</a> Is a new 
      contributer.
   ```

   Link (ID (int), Address (nvarchar(100)), LinkText (nvarchar(max)))
   The tables relation are one To many from Article to link

2.The second solution is that I highly recommend you using no-sql databases like Mongo, Couchbase, etc...